# How can i list my fans name and id?

Tags: php, facebook-fql

I'm a FQL new user!I have a fans page, and I'm a admin. Now,I want to use the FQL to list my  fan's name and fan's id? Please help me!And thanks!

This is what I've tried so far -

```
<?php 
    require_once('src/facebook.php'); 

    $facebook = new Facebook(
                    array( 'appId' => 'id', 
                           'secret' => 'secret', 
                           'cookie' => true, )); 
    $result = $facebook->api(
                   array( 'method' => 'fql.query', 
                          'query' => 'select uid from page_fan 
                                       where page_id = xxxxxx' )); 
    $fb_fans = $result[0]['uid']; 
?> 
<?php 
    echo $fb_fans; 
?>
```

and it shows the following error -

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: 190: Invalid OAuth access token signature. thrown in
>
> C:\AppServ\www\src\base_facebook.php on line 1106

Now it work at:

```
<?php  
require_once('src/facebook.php');  
$facebook = new Facebook(array(  
    'appId'  => 'myid',  
    'secret' => 'secret',  
    'cookie' => true,  
));  
$result = $facebook->api(array(  
    'method' => 'fql.query',  
    'query' => 'select fan_count from page where page_id = xxxx'  
));  
$fb_fans = $result[0]['fan_count'];  
?>  
<?php echo $fb_fans; ?>
```

But now I write 'select uid from page_fan where page_id = xxxx'
it's not work!why?
I guess uid from the page_fan is a table format?

This is my full code:

```
<?php 
    require_once('src/facebook.php'); 

    $facebook = new Facebook(
                    array( 'appId' => 'id', 
                           'secret' => 'secret', 
                           'cookie' => true, )); 
    $result = $facebook->api(
                   array( 'method' => 'fql.query', 
                          'query' => 'select uid from page_fan 
                                       where page_id = xxxxxx' )); 
    $fb_fans = $result[0]['uid']; 
?> 
<?php 
    echo $fb_fans; 
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I had been do my best.But it let me feel down.And I really hope someone can help me to slove this problem.

Comment: If you have tried something, then please provide the code with your question.

Comment: <?php  
require_once('src/facebook.php');  
$facebook = new Facebook(array(  
    'appId'  => 'id',  
    'secret' => 'secret',  
    'cookie' => true,  
));  
$result = $facebook->api(array(  
    'method' => 'fql.query',  
    'query' => 'select uid from page_fan where page_id = xxxxxx'  
));  
$fb_fans = $result[0]['uid'];  
?>  
<?php echo $fb_fans; ?>

Comment: @SayemAhmed This is my code, but it not work!And I input my appId, secret and page_id.

Comment: It's show the error: Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: 190: Invalid OAuth access token signature. thrown in C:\AppServ\www\src\base_facebook.php on line 1106 
Thanks!

Comment: See the edit. Next time post your code like this.

Comment: OAuth access token signature, your token is in-correct!

Comment: @SayemAhmed OK!Thanks!I'm understand it!

Comment: look at the example here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the php sdk?

If so, have you tried to play around with the graph API?

```
$ret = $facebook->api( array(
                         'method' => 'fql.query',
                         'query' => 'SELECT . . . ',
                     ));
```

Or you can have a play with the [explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=1537957009)

Edit:

try something like this:

```
// Make sure you have a token to do so beforehand

$fql = $facebook->api( array(
       'method' => 'fql.query',
       'query' => 'SELECT uid2 FROM friends WHERE uid1=me()',
));

var_dump(json_decode($fql, true)); // test the responce
```

**I dont see any tokens in your code!**

**From the fb source**

*change page_id=XXX to your page ID*

```
$app_id = 'YOUR_APP_ID';
  $app_secret = 'YOUR_APP_SECRET';
  $my_url = 'POST_AUTH_URL';

  $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

 //auth user
 if(empty($code)) {
    $dialog_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=' 
    . $app_id . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($my_url) ;
    echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
  }

  //get user access_token
  $token_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='
    . $app_id . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($my_url) 
    . '&client_secret=' . $app_secret 
    . '&code=' . $code;
  $access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

  // Run fql query
  $fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
    . '/fql?q=SELECT+uid+FROM+page_fan+WHERE+page_id=XXXX'
    . '&' . $access_token;
  $fql_query_result = file_get_contents($fql_query_url);
  $fql_query_obj = json_decode($fql_query_result, true);

  //display results of fql query
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r("query results:");
  print_r($fql_query_obj);
  echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Yes!I'm using the php sdk!I had been use the graph API, but it not work!And get an error code.

Comment: I'm try it!But it still got an error. Thanks!

Comment: can you post your full code into your question, it looks to me like your not requesting a token properly.

Comment: I'm renew!It's my full code. Thanks!

Comment: OK!I'm change xxx to my page_id.This resource I had been tried.By it still not work.Very appreciate you!

Comment: Philip Can I ask you?How can I get an access token?

Answer (score 1):

From this page you can get ids of your fans..
[facebook manual page_fan table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan/)

Then from uids you can get name by following:

```
SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid in ()
```

Comment: Dear Rajat Singhal:
Can you show me more detail?Because I'm a new php user. And I'm not be sure about how to use the fql.Thanks!

Comment: page_fan seems no longer works, but I don't know why Facebook still remains doc there.